# "IOException: Cannot locate resource X" in custom control but the application works

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using the following code for my custom component (in styles in Generic.xaml):

```
<Label Name="Title">
    <Label.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/images/title.gif"></ImageBrush>
     </Label.Background>
     Dummy Title 
</Label>
```

This works. The application is fine. Everything compiles and runs without the issue. But I keep getting the error in XAML "Cannot locate resource 'images/title.gif'" everywhere I include my custom component. If I remove the background setting, the error disappears. I get the same error with every other image in project, and I don't get any errors using the same image elsewhere, in non-custom components.

What the hell is going on?

Comment: Have you added file in current assembly at path `images/title.gif`? And you are you using custom control from same assembly?

Comment: so, are we talking about visual studio designer showing the error? You  might benefit if you directly say the "name" of assembly in the ImageSource "pack" syntax.

Comment: @RohitVats I'm pretty sure that the file is added, since it actually works properly, the image is displayed as background.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa Yes, the error is only in designer. The program is built without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing around in designer, I've managed to solve this. The generated code is as follows:

```
<Label Name="Title" >
    <Label.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/ProjName;component/images/title.gif"/>
    </Label.Background> 
    Dummy Title
</Label>
```

I have no idea what this URI format is, but VS generates it like that.